# Can diffuse backing generate different background color other than black?

Tags: baking

When I create a new image, I choose white BG color.
But after baking, it turns black.
Is there a way to make it white after baked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your bake settings, disable *Clear Image* option:

[image]

Comment: If I did that, many texture images get baked in different position according to each UV map. I have multiple UV Map.

Comment: @JuanFeju can you elaborate? Your baking workflow is probably wrong. *Clear Image* removes the contents of the image before baking to it. If you want to have white background, create a white image and bake to it without clearing it.

Comment: Never mind, it works now. But what does clear image actually for?

Comment: @JuanFeju Typically it's used to overlay multiple bakes.